# Retrieve metrics from videos using YouTube Analytics API

Tags: python, youtube-api

I am trying to retrieve metrics (view counts, number of shares, likes, dislikes, etc.) for YouTube videos. These videos are not on my channel, and they are not on the same channel. I have read many tutorials, and all of them are teaching how to retrieve reports from a channel.

- So my question is, will I be able to retrieve metrics for others' videos without specifying a channel?
- Is YouTube Analytics API only for analyzing channels?

FYI, I am writing in Python. It would be great if someone can recommend some tutorials.

Comment: This is a youtube api related question not a python one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remember that the data within youtube analytics is private user data. In order to access private user data you must be [authorized](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/guides/authorization) by the user to access it.

> So my question is, will I be able to retrieve metrics for others' videos without specifying a channel?

Analytics is channel based. Not video based. So now

> Is YouTube Analytics API only for analyzing channels?

Yes YouTube analytics is designed to work on a channel itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So I assume there is no way that I can acquire statistics like #shares, #dislikes for specific videos (not for a channel) without having owner permissions? I am asking because we are trying to analyze a large number of videos and it's impossible to get permissions from every owner.